# Should we migrate old Robotics questions to the new Robotics Beta site when it opens?

Tags: discussion

With the latest combined [Robotics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics?referrer=syQQzIPHn2qGWzVZGV-6iw2) proposal now very close to full commitment, I was wondering whether we should consider migrating old questions which are about robotics, but *not* about electronics to the new stack exchange site, when it comes out of private beta.

It seems clear that new questions that are about robotics, but *not* about electronics *should* be migrated, when deemed appropriate by the community and our moderators, but should we consider migrating questions which *predate* the creation of the Robotics site?

Comment: I think questions should always be migrated, but there are weird rules saying you shouldn't. http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/q/124/29

Comment: @endolith I dont think we should in general, but more of  a case by case basis here. If you see something that really needs to get moved, sure, but unless it is the pillar of quality, no. I would also wait until they are decently into public beta and do it slowly as not to flood the site with these questions.

Comment: will migrating break (deep)links / bookmarks? If the answer is "Yes" then I don't think any answered questions should be migrated unless they are currently active.

Comment: @jippie - I think that when a question is migrated, it remains on the original site (hence it appears in the questions list suffixed with *[Migrated]*) but going to that question takes you to the site it was migrated to, so I suspect links will just redirect too.

Answer (score 4):

This might be moot now. [Questions older then 60 days may not be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

This means even if we wanted to we could not migrate most of our content. Sorry. I was going to post an answer saying I was behind it but I would only migrate truly great content and only after the site had built up basic content.

Comment: Fair point... I guess it makes sense to have a deadline, and 2 months is probably long enough that they're dormant

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, from discussions on other sites, migration of existing topics is not normal... this is even in obvious cases of "a better place" (eg Raspberry Pi)

There seems to be a turf war among the Holy Trinity to maintain their influence, by maintaining that such subjects are On Topic here, even though they may be "Even More On Topic" elsewhere.

On one hand, I can understand this, but on the other hand, it suggests that the other places are not truly necessary (not that I entirely agree).

Edited to add: I should add, that Electronics.SE (being a new generation site) hasn't showed such behavior (yet)!

Comment: I suspect that if sites refuse to migrate questions likely to get a better response elsewhere, we will just end up with more [multi-posting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting), which would be a shame.

Comment: @MarkBooth The difference here being that Robotics is not on topic here so the migration is not a case of loosing something we want to hold onto. Have you looked to see how many good robotics questions we have that you would want?

Comment: @Kortuk - I had a quick look through but I'll have a better look once the Robotics Beta goes public. Thanks for your help by the way, that last push was just what we needed, and helped me get my *Promoter* badge on Area 51. *8')

Comment: @MarkBooth I thought it over and I bet if you take a look now you will not find much that actually matches what you need.